Python Reflex WebSockets integration
I'm very interested in Reflex, a pure python framework that compiles into JavaScript (React & Chakra.) What I cannot ascertain from docs is whether Reflex currently supports WebSockets?
The integration w/ APIs seems to be geared around FastAPI, which I'm familiar with; one need only call app.add_api_route.
https://reflex.dev/docs/api-routes/overview/
FastAPI does indeed support websockets, so perhaps the Reflex-WebSocket integration is quite flexible and leans heavily on FastAPI (or backend framework)
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/websockets/
Curious if a more definitive answer is available?
